# pyVISA GPIB GET (group execute trigger)

Tags: python, measurement, visa, gpib, pyvisa

I would like to trigger a few measurement devices at the same time over GPIB. There is a GPIB function "GET" which works with LabVIEW, that I would like to use with pyVISA.

Can I send this global GET command with pyVISA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyVisa class `GPIBInterface` has support for `group_execute_trigger`.

```
 intf.group_execute_trigger(instrument1, instrument2, ...):
```

([Source](http://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/resources.html#pyvisa.resources.GPIBInterface.group_execute_trigger))

**Example:**

```
import visa
rm = visa.ResourceManager()
intf = rm.open_resource('GPIB0::INTFC')
inst1 = rm.open_resource('GPIB0::11::INSTR')
inst2 = rm.open_resource('GPIB0::12::INSTR')
intf.group_execute_trigger(inst1, inst2)
```

([Source](https://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html))

Comment: I'm quite new to python and pyvisa. Could you tell me how to use this GPIBInterface class?

Comment: @Philipp, I added an example, but if this library is new to you, you should go through the tutorial at the link I posted.